# Cannot seem to populate combo box remotely in Extjs

Tags: combobox, extjs4.1

I've tried all manor of things to get this to populate the combo drop-down box.
When typing, say "Apple", it appears to be loading the data but, nothing ends up in the drop down box. Firebug shows the data has been loaded. So, where am I going wrong? Thanks.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', { 
    fieldLabel: 'Basket',
    emptyText : 'Type a fruit name',
        queryMode : 'remote',
        minChars  : 3, 
        fields    : ['id', 'name'], 
        store     : { 
                    proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                callbackKey: 'method',
                url: 'http://www.comparetrainfares.co.uk/train_scripts/data.php',
                reader: {
                root: 'items'
            },
                }
             },
        needleKey     : 'query',
        labelKey      : 'id',
        label         : 'name',
        displayField  : 'name',
        width         : 260, 
        forceSelection: true,
        renderTo      : query1,
});



<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
//header('Content-Type: application/x-json');


// http://www.comparetrainfares.co.uk/train_scripts/data.php

$output = array();

$output[] = array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Apple');
$output[] = array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'Banana');
$output[] = array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'Orange');
$output[] = array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Lemon');

$objects = array('items' => $output);

echo json_encode($objects);
?>
```

Comment: Try adding `type: 'json',` to your `reader` config.

Comment: No that didn't work - I'm sure I have tried that before - thanks.

Comment: show us an example of the output generated by the php script.

Comment: You can view the output of the Php script if you pop this in your browser http://www.comparetrainfares.co.uk/train_scripts/data.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using a jsonp proxy.  This is not the default ajax way of loading the store.  The php script should be receiving a function name from the 'callback' parameter sent to the php script and then the returning data should be in a format like this:

```
callback({"items":[{"id":"1","name":"Apple"},{"id":"2","name":"Banana"},{"id":"3","name":"Orange"},{"id":"4","name":"Lemon"}]})
```

And remember to replace 'callback' with the name of whatever string is being sent in the callback parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you possibly send me an example, as I'm still not getting anywhere fast.

Comment: Just realized that my answer was slightly wrong.  I have updated it.

Comment: I added in the "items" object because that is defined by the jsonp config as the root.

Comment: I'm still not getting anything in the drop down. The data is definitely coming back as I can see it in FireBug!

Comment: please paste exactly what you are seeing in firebug for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get from FireBug when I type the word "Appl" into the combo box. I know the data coming back is different from what I'm typing but, I still don't get anything even when I enter something which should match.

Under the 'Params' tab I see:

```
_dc 1361011625341
callback    Ext.data.JsonP.callback1
limit   10
page    1
query   appl
start   0
```

The 'Response' tab shows:

```
{rows:[{"id":"1","genre_name":"Comedy"},{"id":"2","genre_name":"Drama"},{"id":"3","genre_name":"Action"},{"id":"4","genre_name":"Mystery"}]}
```

The 'JSON' tab shows:

Sort by key

```
rows    
[Object { id=    
"1"    
,  genre_name=    
"Comedy"    
}, Object { id=    
"2"    
,  genre_name=    
"Drama"    
}, Object { id=    
"3"    
,  genre_name=    
"Action"    
}, Object { id=    
"4"    
,  genre_name=    
"Mystery"    
}]    

0
    Object { id=    
"1"    
, genre_name=    
"Comedy"    
}       
1
    Object { id=    
"2"    
, genre_name=    
"Drama"    
}       
2
    Object { id=    
"3"    
, genre_name=    
"Action"    
}       
3
    Object { id=    
"4"    
, genre_name=    
"Mystery"    
}
```